# Select only certain fields from the model using SqlAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use the encode databases library to perform asynchronous queries on the database. The library is based on SQLAlchemy Core expression language. A query that gives all fields works

```
@staticmethod
async def get_user_events_invite_list(pk: int):
    events_invites = await database.fetch_all(query=event_invites.select().where(event_invites.c.to_user == pk).order_by(event_invites.c.created_at))
    return  ([dict(e.items()) for e in events_invites])
```

And return

```
[{'id': 18, 'from_user': 4, 'to_user': 1, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 14, 32, 20, 999835, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'to_event': 1, 'status': <InviteStatus.CREATED: 'CREATED'>, 'type': <InviteType.BET: 'BET'>, 'is_active': True}, ...]
```

I am trying to select only certain fields(**from_user, created_at, to_event**) from a table accordingly [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#setting-the-columns-and-from-clause)

```
events_invites = await database.fetch_all(query=event_invites.select(event_invites.c.from_user, event_invites.c.created_at, event_invites.c.to_event).where(event_invites.c.to_user == pk).order_by(event_invites.c.created_at))
```

but get

```
TypeError: select() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

What am I wrong about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of the query worked

```
events_invites = await database.fetch_all(query=select([event_invites.c.from_user, event_invites.c.created_at, event_invites.c.to_event]).where(event_invites.c.to_user == pk).order_by(event_invites.c.created_at))
```

Maybe someone could use

Comment: Are you using an older version of SQLAlchemy? Before v1.4 the square brackets were required around the columns to be selected.

Comment: I'm usung 1.3.23. Has the syntax changed in the new version? Where can I see the changes?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html#change-5284